# How would a butler/servant refer to his princess?

Tags: idioms, pronouns

I'm looking to translate a catch-phrase into Japanese. It would belong to a servant/butler character, when he confirms a order, or announces his arrival, etc.

Basically "My Queen" / "My Princess" phrase.

Naive translation would be "Boku no Joou" / "Boku no Hime".

However I'm worried that it'd more imply that the princess belongs to him, then him to the princess, and despite using subservient pronoun it'd be rude.

Was there any idiomatic phrase like that in Japanese?

Would he simply state "Surname-sama"?

Answer (score 2):

I think 殿下｛でんか｝ for a princess and 陛下｛へいか｝ for a queen are strictly 'proper', but 王女様｛おうじょさま｝, お姫様｛おひめさま｝, and 女王様｛じょおうさま｝ appear to be pretty common. I think a sort of subservient 'Yes, my queen' for accepting an order might be something like 「かしこまりました、陛下・女王様」.

And if the woman in question isn't *actual* royalty, you should probably go with something like 「お嬢さん｛おじょうさん｝・お嬢様｛おじょうさま｝」.